# Stack Overflow documentation for itself

Tags: discussion, feature-request, documentation

With the abundance of Q&A on Meta, would creating a documentation page on SO for:

- official guidelines
- information on the site
- how it works
- how it should be used
- examples of good question asking
- etc.

Would/should this be something that is created, or will meta be getting its own documentation section?

Comment: Do you mean http://stackoverflow.com/help?

Comment: @Stijn I think what the OP means is the thoroughly spread out discussions and FAQs about editing, reviewing, determining what's on/offtopic and so on.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah, feel free to edit my question with anything you think may be pertinent to the discussion.

Answer (score 12):

We already have one--it's the [faq](/questions/tagged/faq) tag.

[FAQ Index for Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251225/faq-index-for-stack-overflow)

Comment: I often forget we have that, it's not very discoverable.

Comment: Don't forget about the [Stack Exchange FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites) as well.  Lots of great resources in there too.

Answer (score 5):

What I'd like to do is get the information that we have more prominently suggested by the user interface. For instance, we're working on a prototype of a new "ask question" page that would only be shown to very new accounts, where we basically break up the single input box into 4 or 5 and ask for all of the elements that go into a great question separately. I'm hoping to get that into testing within a month.

There's other places where the system should be doing more to guide users into doing things properly, like not targeting their votes disproportionately, where a little just-in-time help would work brilliantly.

Information is only great if it's surfaced, and it doesn't occur to many people that typing a question into an input box would be any more complicated than commenting on a video, so not only do folks not read the manual, it doesn't dawn on them that there might be one.

What we have is great, and useful when pointing out that someone did something incorrectly. I'd like to get more toward helping them not flounder in the first place :)

Comment: Umm... "targeting ... votes disproportionately" is "doing things properly"?

Comment: I uh, might have missed a not there :) Fixed.

Comment: PLEASE have the title be the absolute last input :)

Comment: In this new "ask a question" page, please **please** make it very clear that _"what have you tried"_ does **not** mean _"show the code that does not work"_. Explain that it means _"show what you have tried to get that non-working code to work"_. I'm tired of having that discussion.